# How to save media file in app specific folder using Media Store API - Scoped Storage Android

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11, scoped-storage

I am trying to use scoped storage for Android 10 and above to save images taken from the camera in the app specific folder.
I know how to do it using File API but I am looking for to do it with Media store API.

Here is the issue, using the below code it saves images in Internal storage > Pictures, but doesn't save it in app specific folder. Hence if I uninstall the app, the images saved by the app still remains in the memory. I want them to get deleted automatically if user removes the app from his phone.

Let me know if I am doing it wrong or missing something.

```
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() throws IOException {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            if (!checkIfVersionCodeQAndAbove()) {
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    return;
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", createImageFile());
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                }
            }
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
        }
    }


private void storeImageUsingMediaApi(Intent data) {
        if (getActivity()!=null) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, imageFileName + ".jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "profile_image");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES  + File.separator + "MyApp");

            ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

            OutputStream stream = null;
            Uri uri = null;
            try {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                if (extras != null) {
                    bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                }

                final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues);

                if (uri == null) {
                    throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
                }

                stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);

                if (stream == null) {
                    throw new IOException("Failed to get output stream.");
                }

                if (bitmap!=null && !bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, stream)) {
                    throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
                }

                stream.close();

                selctedImageUri = String.valueOf(uri);

                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(uri).into(imageProfile);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (uri != null) {
                    // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
                    resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }






@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        CgUtils.showLog(getTag(), "frag onActivityResult");

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
                CgUtils.showLog(getTag(), "frag TAKE_PICTURE");

                if (checkIfVersionCodeQAndAbove()) {
                    storeImageUsingMediaApi(data);
                } else {
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(selctedImageUri);
                    if (imageUri.getPath() != null) {
                        File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
                        try {
                            InputStream ims = new FileInputStream(file);
                            imageProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            CgUtils.showLog(TAG, "error " + e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!selctedImageUri.isEmpty()) {
                    if (null != loginResponse)
                        loginResponse.setImageUri(selctedImageUri);
                    new InsertLoginResponse(getActivity(), loginResponse, false).executeOnExecutor(CgUtils.getExecutorType());

                    sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(CgConstants.USER_PROF_PIC, selctedImageUri);
                    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
                }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Do not use the media store then. Just write them to app specific directory yourself.

Comment: Further your bitmap will always be null as you use and do not use photoFile and photoUri. And with createImageFile you can create the file in app specific directory already.

Comment: @blackapps I was trying to do it with media store API. Isn't it possible?

Comment: No. As the media store will not touch your app specific directory.